# ASP.NET Core not catching exception if the URI contains invalid excape characters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have different uri to redirect to if the original uri to redirect to contains invalid escape characters(Eg. \r , \n ). This is inside a ApiController that is inherited from ControllerBase of ASP.NET core.

```
        try
        {
            return Redirect(uriString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Redirect(uriError);
        }
```

Here, uriString is the original uri but it contains excape characters - \r and \n. So, it redirects to this page: 
[image]

But, I want it to catch this exception and redirect to uriError page that is inside catch.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use global exception handler (exception middleware) for this scenario. 
or use can try to convert the string to Url and handle the exception. 
in your case return Redirect(""); will return the control and the URL checking will happen in the pipeline. so either you can create global exception handler to handle all the exception in the pipeline or try to perse string to URL. 

for global exception handler -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-handler-lambda 
**OR**

Instead of all this, you can directly configure error page in startup like this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#developer-exception-page

Comment: Yeah.. a middleware or action filter can catch the exception. It occurs during result execution, not result creation which is being done in OP's code. Redirect() just returns an action result which is executed by the framework after the function exits.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect terminates the current context.
You can't catch a redirect and then choose to redirect to different URL because it's already redirected.
This is by design and it makes sense.

There's a way of catching exceptions of redirects but mostly for logging purposes only, not for redirecting again.
Why don't you validate the URL by yourself?

```
if(yourCustomUrlValidator(uriString))
{
   return Redirect(uriString);
}
else
{
   return Redirect(uriError);
}
```

You may also use the following .net core built in validation

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
```

Another approach is to use a middleware to handle exception and redirecting to error page, but it would work only for exception that may occur before the Redirect method.
You can read about it here:
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/20/custom-error-pages-asp-net-core/

Your other option is to handle the redirect error in the client side.